# CSS de IDs diferentes para as mesmas Classes

Tags: css, classes, id

Como posso aplicar os mesmos atributos e as mesmas classes mas com iDs de produtos diferentes?
O seguinte código esta funcionando porem acho que dá para simplificar esse CSS

```
.postid-2201 .product .summary .cart .quantity {margin: 0px; display: none;}
.postid-3526 .product .summary .cart .quantity {margin: 0px; display: none;}
.postid-3532 .product .summary .cart .quantity {margin: 0px; display: none;}

.postid-2201 .product_title {display: none;}
.postid-3526 .product_title {display: none;} 
.postid-3532 .product_title {display: none;} 

.postid-2201 .product_meta {display: none;}
.postid-3526 .product_meta {display: none;}
.postid-3532 .product_meta {display: none;}

.postid-2201 .product .entry-summary .price {display: none;}
.postid-3526 .product .entry-summary .price {display: none;}
.postid-3532 .product .entry-summary .price {display: none;}

.postid-2201 .fusion-separator.sep-solid {display: none;}
.postid-3526 .fusion-separator.sep-solid {display: none;}
.postid-3532 .fusion-separator.sep-solid {display: none;}

.postid-2201 .mnm_message_content {margin: 0 0 0 10px; border: 0;}
.postid-3526 .mnm_message_content {margin: 0 0 0 10px; border: 0;}
.postid-3532 .mnm_message_content {margin: 0 10px 0 10px; border: 0;}

.postid-2201 .woocommerce-error {display: none;}
.postid-3526 .woocommerce-error {display: none;}
.postid-3532 .woocommerce-error {display: none;}

.postid-2201 form.cart {margin: 0px; display: grid;}
.postid-3526 form.cart {margin: 0px; display: grid;}
.postid-3532 form.cart {margin: 0px; display: grid;}

.postid-2201 button.single_add_to_cart_button.button.alt.disabled { background-color: #dadada; cursor:Default;}
.postid-3526 button.single_add_to_cart_button.button.alt.disabled { background-color: #dadada; cursor:Default;}
.postid-3532 button.single_add_to_cart_button.button.alt.disabled { background-color: #dadada; cursor:Default;}
```

Comment: a `.postid-3532 .mnm_message_content {margin: 0 10px 0 10px; border: 0;}` é diferente das outras mesmo ?

Comment: Tentei colocar dessa forma mas nao funcionou:
.postid-2201.postid-3526.postid-3532 .product .summary .cart .quantity {margin: 0px; display: none;}

Comment: Sim Pedro, Cada postid é um produto que esta no Woocommerce e eu quero aplicar esse css apenas nesses 3 produtos

Answer (score 3):

Você consegue fazer isso manipulando o seletor do elemento, no caso usei `^=` que irá selecionar todos os elementos que começa com `classe-`, ou seja, irá atribuir a propriedade `background-color` para os elementos `p` que tenham uma classe que comece com `classe-`

```css
p[class^="classe-"]{
    background-color: #f00
}
```

```html
<p class="classe-1">Texto 1</p>
<p class="classe-2">Texto 2</p>
<p class="classe-3">Texto 3</p>
<p class="classe-4">Texto 4</p>
```

> Nesse caso todos os `postid` receberam a estilização.

---

- No seu caso, como queres apenas nesses três `postid`, então basta criar seletores agrupados, já que iram receber a mesma estilização, ficaria dessa forma:

  ```
  .postid-2201 .product .summary .cart .quantity,
  .postid-3526 .product .summary .cart .quantity,
  .postid-3532 .product .summary .cart .quantity { margin: 0px; display: none }

  .postid-2201 .product_title,
  .postid-3526 .product_title, 
  .postid-3532 .product_title, 
  .postid-2201 .product_meta,
  .postid-3526 .product_meta,
  .postid-3532 .product_meta,
  .postid-2201 .product .entry-summary .price,
  .postid-3526 .product .entry-summary .price,
  .postid-3532 .product .entry-summary .price,
  .postid-2201 .fusion-separator.sep-solid,
  .postid-3526 .fusion-separator.sep-solid,
  .postid-3532 .fusion-separator.sep-solid,
  .postid-2201 .woocommerce-error,
  .postid-3526 .woocommerce-error,
  .postid-3532 .woocommerce-error { display: none }

  .postid-2201 .mnm_message_content,
  .postid-3526 .mnm_message_content,
  .postid-3532 .mnm_message_content { margin: 0 10px 0 10px; border: 0 }

  .postid-2201 form.cart,
  .postid-3526 form.cart,
  .postid-3532 form.cart { margin: 0px; display: grid }

  .postid-2201 button.single_add_to_cart_button.button.alt.disabled,
  .postid-3526 button.single_add_to_cart_button.button.alt.disabled,
  .postid-3532 button.single_add_to_cart_button.button.alt.disabled { background-color: #dadada; cursor:Default }
  ```

---

#### Referência: [Seletores](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors)

Comment: Obrigado!
Sou meio leigo no assunto, este css eu coloquei no "Custom CSS" do meu template no Wordpress. Como faço para limitar o postid para apenas esses  3 produtos (2201, 3526 e 3532)?
Caso contrario vai aplicar em todos, não é isso?

Comment: Caso seja produtos diferentes terá que usar `.postid-1, postid-2, postid-3{ ... }`, separando por virgulas cada seletor

Comment: Alterei a resposta

Comment: Valeu Pedro! Já ajudou bastante.